# Sublime Text: quickly access files outside the current project

Tags: workflow, sublimetext2

To facilitate code reuse across projects, I set up this (quick and dirty) method to access recent projects.

[image: Screenshot of links to folders]

In the current project, I add a link (*z-themes*) to a folder that contains links to recent projects. This enabled me to access those files without having to open the whole project (this worked in Espresso).

In Sublime Text, links are not followed and symlinks mess with the file search (files in the linked folders appear in the **Go to file** panel, so I might open the wrong file)

The question is: **how do easily I access files in predefined folders outside the current project?**

Plugins and alternative workflows are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use now: I created a *previous projects* "project" just for the older files.

[image: Project folders in apposite project]

- simple to add projects (drag their folder to the sidebar)
- use Sublime's file search across **all** the files
- old projects' files are separated from the current project
- no plugins to update/figure out

Only thing is that I'll have to keep a separate window open just for this, but it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like [FuzzyFileNav](https://github.com/facelessuser/FuzzyFileNav)? That plugin allows you to set up bookmarks to a particular folder. You can then navigate through folders as you would normally in the file system.

Comment: That is perfect, except I can't make it work correctly. Fuzzy-searched files and folders can't be managed (nor autocompleted with `tab`), so I'd have to type the whole name to just copy it. I can't find similar plugins, unfortunately.

Comment: @bfred.it Odd, I can tab autocomplete filenames/folders with tab. It may be worthwhile creating an issue on the github page. If I recall, the developer is pretty good about responding. Though he may be more busy than normal now since he is probably porting his plugins to ST3.

Comment: It does autocomplete files **unless** you fuzzy-search them. Take this, for example: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2475i.png I can't do anything with the filtered file. I'll open an issue ;)

Comment: Ah got it. That makes sense. Guess I missed that "Fuzzy-searched" part of what you said =). As a plugin developer, I don't know it if it is possible in ST2 since you don't know what is selected until it has been selected. But I believe there is a new callback in ST3 that would allow for that feature. Of course, his plugins are better than mine, so he will probably know better =)

Answer (score 0):

I found [Goto Folder](https://github.com/freewizard/SublimeGotoFolder): it's very simplistic and doesn't allow for any file management like FuzzyFileNav does (which *could* be nice) but it allows for simple bookmarks and it behaves well.

Edit: I also found [FileBinder](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/FileBinder)